# System.exit return code isn't detected by bash eval

Tags: java, bash, error-handling

struggling with this for an hour... java code:

```
ULogger.info("throwing out 666!");
System.exit(666);
```

bash wrapper:

```
eval ${COMMAND_TO_RUN}
ret_code=$?
printf "error code : [%d]" ${ret_code}
```

output:

```
[2012-11-30 15:20:12,971][INFO ] throwing out 666!
error code : [0]
```

what's the deal here? Thanks...

[EDIT]

The `${COMMAND_TO_RUN}` is

```
((java -Xmx9000m -Dtoday_nix=20121128 -cp "/usr/lib/hadoop/conf" com.paypal.risk.ars.linking.task_fw.BaseRunnableProcess 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) | tee /dev/tty) > batches_errors.log
```

Comment: Please add more of your bash wrapper code, especially what `COMMAND_TO_RUN` is. I suspect the reason for this in there.

Comment: Process exit codes are often truncated to 8 bits, so you're probably not going to get 666 via `$?` regardless.  You might get 154 or -102 depending on your platform.

Comment: Also, do you have a `SecurityManager` installed?

Comment: I get 154 on OS X and on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: added command_to_run as requested. I think i see where this is going.. was it wrong of me to use the tee and the redirection to log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in your `COMMAND_TO_RUN`:

```
((java -Xmx9000m -Dtoday_nix=20121128 -cp "/usr/lib/hadoop/conf" com.paypal.risk.ars.linking.task_fw.BaseRunnableProcess 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) | tee /dev/tty) > batches_errors.log
```

The last program called is `tee`, which will exit with status `0`, overriding the exit
value of `java`.

You can use `$PIPESTATUS`, which is an array of return values in the pipe.

For example:

```
$ cat nonexistantFile | echo ; echo "e: $? p: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

Expected output:

```
e: 0 p: 1 0
```

`cat` will fail (exit code 1), echo will succeed (exit code 0). `$?` will be `0`.
`${PIPESTATUS[0]}` will contain the exit code for `cat` (`1`) and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` the one for echo (`0`).

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that $PIPESTATUS existed

Comment: very neat! but still `(cat nonexistantFile | echo) ; echo "e: $? p: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` doesn't work - because of the parentheses thing, which is a trick I don't want to give up on (from here: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/60370-redirecting-stderr-message-stdout-file-same-time.html)

Answer (score -2):

This is because $? is almost certainly giving you the return code of `eval`, which is succeeding here. Why are you including the `eval` call in there? Just call the `COMMAND_TO_RUN`

Comment: `eval` reports as its exit code the result of the process that it spawned.  From http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23116 : "This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of eval."