# bash script that directs stderr to file, stdout+stderr to terminal, and returns exit code

Tags: bash, error-handling, stdout, stderr

this is a better phrasing of what I intended in [System.exit return code isn't detected by bash eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654633/java-system-exit-return-code-isnt-detected-by-bash-eval). I need a bash script that

1. runs an application (in my case it's a java app)
2. directs stderr to a file
3. directs stderr + stdout to the terminal
4. returns the exit code of the app

for some reason, this is hard to do, even though it's seems to me like a standard config for enterprise applications...
Thanks!

[EDIT]

testing solutions by wrapping this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This is Standard Out"
echo "This is Standard Error" >&2
cat meow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do your requirements :

```
#!/bin/bash

errlog="/var/log/my_app"

exec 2> >(tee "$errlog")

java -jar /path/to/app.jar

exit $?
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `exec 2 >` catch STDERR (if you provide a file on the right, STDERR will be redirected in this file and no more on the terminal)
- `>( )` is a bash [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (this create file descriptors in background)
- `tee` is there to both displays STDERR on the terminal & to save STDERR to the logfile

Comment: this is great. So when would I want to use tee without process substitution?

Comment: `tee` is useful to both display on the terminal and writing to a file : http://pastie.org/5468341 See `man 1 tee`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Save old stdout
exec 3>&1
# Redirect stderr to pipe, stdout to saved descriptor, pipe goes to tee
app_command 2>&1 >&3 | tee errorfile
# close temporary descriptor now that app is done
exec 3>&-
```