# Why does bash eval return zero when backgrounded command fails?

Tags: bash, eval

Editing this post, original is at bottom beneath the "Thanks!"

```
command='a.out arg1 arg2 &'
eval ${command}
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   printf "Command \'${command}\' failed\n"
   exit 1
fi
wait
```

Here is a test script that demonstrates the problem, which I oversimplified
in the original post. Notice the ampersand in line 2 and the wait command.
These more faithfully represent my script. In case it matters, the ampersand
is sometimes there and sometimes not, its presence is determined by a user-
specified flag that indicates whether or not to background a long arithmetic
calculation. And, also in case it matters, I'm actually backgrounding many
(twelve) processes, i.e., `${command[0..11]}`. I want the script to die if any
fail. I use 'wait' to synchronize the successful return of all processes.
Happy (sort of) to use another approach but this *almost* works.

The ampersand  (for backgrounding) seems to cause the problem.
When `${command}` omits the ampersand, the script runs as expected:
The executable a.out is not found, a complaint to that effect is issued,
and $? is non-zero so the host script exits. When `${command}` includes
the ampersand, the same complaint is issued but $? is zero so the
script continues to execute. I want the script to die immediately when
a.out fails but how do I obtain the non-zero return value from a
backgrounded process?

Thanks!

(original post):

I have a bash script that uses commands of the form

```
eval ${command}
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   printf "Command ${command} failed"
   exit 1
fi
```

where ${command} is a string of words, e.g., "a.out arg1 ... argn".
The problem is that the return code from eval (i.e., `$?`) is always
zero even when `${command}` fails. Removing the "eval" from the above
snippet allows the correct return code (`$?`) to be returned and thus
halt the script. I need to keep my command string in a variable
(`${command}`) in order to manipulate it elsewhere, and simply running 
`${command}` without the eval doesn't work well for other reasons. How do I catch the
correct return code when using eval?

Thanks!
Charlie

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654633/java-system-exit-return-code-isnt-detected-by-bash-eval

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. A quick check of `eval true` and `eval false` showed `$?` behaves as expected.

Comment: Also, I question the need for `eval`. Can you show exactly why you need it? There's probably a way to do the same thing without it.

Comment: (1) `eval` does return the exit code of the command.  If you are really not seeing that, you need to tell us what is in `${command}`.   (2) Good bash code almost never uses `eval`.  If you think you need `eval` here, you might want to explain why and see if people here can provide a better approach.

Comment: what's wrong with just doing `$command || echo "$command failed" && exit 1`

Comment: Bash manual for [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-eval) says:

   _`eval [arguments]`

    The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the return status is zero._  What you are seeing goes against what the manual says, therefore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The ampersand (for backgrounding) seems to cause the problem.

That is correct.

The shell cannot know a command's exit code until the command completes.  When you put a command in background, the shell *does not wait* for completion.  Hence, it cannot know the (future) return status of the command in background.

This is documented in `man bash`:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish,  and  the return  status is 0.

In other words, the return code after putting a command in background is always 0 because the shell cannot predict the future return code of a command that has not yet completed.

If you want to find the return status of commands in the background, you need to use the `wait` command.

#### Examples

The command `false` always sets a return status of 1:

```
$ false ; echo status=$?
status=1
```

Observe, though, what happens if we background it:

```
$ false & echo status=$?
[1] 4051
status=0
```

The status is 0 because the command was put in background and the shell cannot predict its future exit code.  If we wait a few moments, we will see:

```
$ 
[1]+  Exit 1                  false
```

Here, the shell is notifying us that the brackground task completed and its return status was just as it should be: 1.

In the above, we did not use `eval`.  If we do, nothing changes:

```
$ eval 'false &' ; echo status=$?
[1] 4094
status=0
$ 
[1]+  Exit 1                  false
```

If you do want the return status of a backgrounded command, use wait.  For example, this shows how to capture the return status of `false`:

```
$ false & wait $!; echo status=$?
[1] 4613
[1]+  Exit 1                  false
status=1
```

Comment: but isn't `command & wait $!` just equal to `command` without setting it to background?

Comment: @stimur Yes.  The purpose here of `command & wait $!` is as a vehicle for teaching about how the shell handles commands run in the background.  As an aside, a similar but potentially useful case would be `command & other_commands; wait $!`

Answer (score 1):

From the man page on my system:

*eval [arg ...] The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.*

If your system documentation is 'the same', then, most likely, whatever commands you are running are the problem, i.e. 'a.out' is returning '0' on exit instead of a non-zero value.  Add appropriate 'exit return code' to your compiled program.

You might also try using $() which will 'run' your binary instead of 'evaluating' it..., i.e.

STATUS=$(a.out var var var)

As long on only one 'command' is in the stream, then the value of $? is the 'exit code'; otherwise, $? is the return code for the last command in a multi-command 'pipe'...

:)
Dale